# Foreign keys have random number appended when using Hibernate's TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance

Tags: hibernate, foreign-keys, hbm2ddl

I currently have the following in my domain model:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Entity
abstract class Item {
    @ManyToOne
    @ForeignKey(name="FK_ITEM_ORG")
    @JoinColumn(name="ORG_ID")
    private Organization org
}

@Table(name = "ItemA")
public class ItemA extends Item {}

@Table(name = "ItemB")
public class ItemA extends Item {}
```

Hibernate's HBM2DDL creates 2 tables for this mapping: `ItemA` and `ItemB`. Both have the `ORG_ID` column and a foreign key to the `Organization` table. However, each foreign key has a random number appended (ie FK_ITEM_ORG98343). How can I specify what foreign key each table uses? For example, I want to have `FK_ITEMA_ORG` and `FK_ITEMB_ORG`.

**Update**

Please also see the follow-on question: [Is the ForeignKey annotation only used by HBM2DDL to generate the schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683757/is-the-foreignkey-annotation-only-used-by-hbm2ddl-to-generate-the-schema)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to remove annotation from field in main class and move it to method in each children with providing FK name.

Something like that:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Entity
public abstract class Item {
    private Organization  org;
    public Organization getOrg() {
        return org;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "ItemA")
public class ItemA extends Item {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ORG_ID")
    @ForeignKey(name="FK_ITEM_ORG_1")
    public Organization getOrg(){
        return super.getOrg();
    }
}


public class ItemB extends Item{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ORG_ID")
    @ForeignKey(name="FK_ITEM_ORG_2")
    public Organization getOrg(){
        return super.getOrg();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing this also means I can't use field-level annotations? Or is it possible to combine field and method level?

Comment: It's possible to combine. See @Access annotation for details.

Comment: Besides, also Naming Strategy could help you if you wish to globally redefine FK names, for instance http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-namingstrategy

Comment: Great idea! If you have any thoughts on my follow up question I linked to above I'd appreciate it :)