# Is the ForeignKey annotation only used by HBM2DDL to generate the schema?

Tags: hibernate, foreign-keys, hbm2ddl

I'm having an issue with how Hibernate generates foreign key names when using the TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance strategy: [Foreign keys have random number appended when using Hibernate's TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683686/foreign-keys-have-random-number-appended-when-using-hibernates-table-per-class-i)

So I'm wondering if I can simply replace the annotation with the following:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Entity
abstract class Item {
    @ManyToOne
    @ForeignKey(name="FK_ITEM_ORG_CHANGEME")
    @JoinColumn(name="ORG_ID")
    private Organization org
}
```

That way I always know to go back to the generated DDL and replace all occurrences of CHANGEME. Does Hibernate do anything else with the `@ForeignKey` attribute that I'm not aware of or is this a good workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible, you could redefine such behavior via own Naming staretgy - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/cfg/NamingStrategy.html#foreignKeyColumnName(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) ?

Comment: Great, thanks! Do you know btw if my assumption is correct (@ForeignKey is only used by HBM2DDL)?

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, @ForeignKey is only used by HBM2DDL (or its little brother that generate a domain model from an existing database but you are not using that it seems).